# What is the SMTP 'NOOP' command used for?

Tags: email, smtp

What is the purpose of the NOOP in the SMTP spec?

It says:

```
   This command does not affect any parameters or previously entered
   commands.  It specifies no action other than that the receiver send a
   "250 OK" reply.

   This command has no effect on the reverse-path buffer, the forward-
   path buffer, or the mail data buffer, and it may be issued at any
   time.  If a parameter string is specified, servers SHOULD ignore it.

   Syntax:

      noop = "NOOP" [ SP String ] CRLF
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A quick google check, turned this up ([source](http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-pt/magazine/2005.11.howitworkssmtp%28en-us%29.aspx)):

> The simplest of these commands is NOOP, useful mostly in testing to avoid timeouts; it does nothing and can generate only a successful response, with no change in state...

Answer (score 3):

On IIS 5.0, 7.5 and possibly other versions, sending too many NOOPs will get you in trouble as I found out recently. IIS will return this: "421 Too many errors on this connection---closing" and close the connection on you.

Here is a [reference](http://www.44342.com/iis-f131-t207-p1.htm) to someone who encountered this same problem...

Here is a cryptic reference to this on microsoft's support site [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/155455).

> NOOP CRLF
>
> The SMTP-receiver should send a 250 reply to the NO OPERATION command.
>   The only other possible responses are a 500 reply, indicating
>   incorrect command syntax, or the 421 reply, indicating that the SMTP
>   service will be shutting down shortly.

Comment: Interesting. I would assume this is the case with most SMTP servers (not only Microsoft), as a security against someone wanting to DoS you by keeping connections open for days and days through NOOPs.

Comment: I don't think its due to a security issue. Other servers don't exhibit this problem. The RFC doesn't specify how to deal with DOS, just the messaging protocol. Security would be handled via other params such as connection timeouts, send limits, etc. The workaround was to use the RSET command instead of NOOP.

Comment: What do you mean with connection timeout? That the server closes the connection after `x` seconds regardless of the state of the current transaction? That could make sense. Would have to be a relatively high value to avoid closing connection in the middle of something though, no?

Comment: Yes, you can set parameters such as connection timeouts. On Exchange it is 10 mins by default. However, here, the issue was that IIS was closing connection once it received 15 or so NOOP requests.

Comment: I'm currently tracking an issue with NOOP on Mandrill's servers (they serve MailChimp's mail) and it is explicitly exhibiting this "Too Many Errors" behaviour which appears to be both punitive and long lived in that NEW connections auto error as well for a period of time. Tech support specifically listed NOOPs and being a source of problems.